# Can I use PDFBox in an applet?

Tags: java, pdf, printing, applet, pdfbox

I trying to use PDFBox in an applet, because I need to print a report, but the computer client can't install anything.  Can I use the src or class from PDFBox in an applet?

Answer (score 1):

It seems PDFBox is pure Java.  So to access the functionality of the PDFBox API, put it on the run-time class-path of the applet.  To do that, add a reference to each Jar of the API into the `archive` attribute of the applet element.

It is probable that all Jars will need to be digitally signed in order to gain the permission to print (though more recent JREs are supposed to offer prompted printing).